# Importing only several fields from an ODBC database table into an access table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba, odbc

This works for importing an entire table from the ODBC database into Access:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;DSN=SuperBase", acTable, "BDONAMES", "BDONAMES", False
```

But there is a table in the ODBC database with 517 fields and I only want to import, let's say, 5 or 6 columns/fields.  What is the best way to do this using VBA?  I googled for a couple days and read 10 or 15 threads on stackoverflow but I haven't seen this specific question answered.  Thanks in advance

Comment: I could create a connection to the ODBC, create a recordset from SQL containing only the criteria/fields I want, but I don't know the best way to create a table from that recordset (maintaining the correct data types, field length, and all other field information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something on the lines of:

```
sSQL="SELECT This,That,TheOther,Columns INTO BDONames " _
   & "FROM [ODBC;DSN=SuperBase].BDONAMES"
CurrentDB.Execute sSQL
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: WORKS! I knew it would be something simple

Comment: hey @Remou, I had another problem.  This works: AC.CurrentDb.Execute "select business_name,boc_num_string into loans from [odbc;dsn=superbase].loans where boc_num_string='1234'" but this next one gives me "Too Few Parameters. Expected 1".  AC.CurrentDb.Execute "select ace_borrower,boc_num_string into loans from [odbc;dsn=superbase].loans where boc_num_string='1234'".  I know the ace_borrower column exists.  Any ideas?

Comment: @brettville No, other than check the spelling etc. It certainly looks like it does not believe in `ace_borrower`

Comment: @Remous Hm, so weird.  It's spelled correctly, not case sensitive.  Can't figure it out.  The column pulls in fine doing an excel ODBC data import

Comment: @Remous the excel datatable query that works just fine is this:
SELECT LOANS.BOC_NUM_STRING, LOANS.ACE_BORROWER
FROM LOANS LOANS
WHERE (LOANS.BOC_NUM_STRING='12345')

Comment: @brettville Okay. Try a select query, we can always use it as a sub query. `SELECT l.BOC_NUM_STRING, l.ACE_BORROWER FROM [ODBC;DSN=SuperBase].Loans As l WHERE l.BOC_NUM_STRING='12345'`

Comment: @Remous "Too few parameters. Expected 1".  I tried running it with ADODB connection and recordset objects. It said "[Superbase Developers plc.][Superbase ODBC Driver]Unexpected extra token: As". So it looks like Superbase doesn't support "AS"?

Comment: It does ( http://www.superbase.com/sbdocu/sbodbc/sbodbc35.htm ) But possibly not in that way. I was hoping to Alias, but I do not know superbase SQL. You could try leaving out AS - that works in Access and SQL Server, so it may work here : `FROM [ODBC;DSN=SuperBase].Loans l` What is the story with `FROM LOANS LOANS` in your example (above). I thought it was a typo, but perhaps it is an alias, or something else?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this.  It's driving me nuts.  When I import external data into excel, I select superbase (the dsn set up in ODBC sources), I pick fields ace_borrower and boc_num_string and add a criteria for boc_num_string equals '12345'.  It imports fine. In excel I did ?activesheet.querytables(1).commandtext and that is the SQL excel is using for the query table

Comment: "Too Few Parameters. Expected 1" :(  SELECT blah.BOC_NUM_STRING, blah.ACE_BORROWER INTO Loans FROM [ODBC;DSN=SuperBase].Loans blah WHERE blah.BOC_NUM_STRING='12345'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5700/discussion-between-brettville-and-remou)